# Is there a way to provide failure message with ExpectedException attribute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, expected-exception

I want to provide a message when assertion has failed but I can't figure out a way to do it.

```
[Test]
public void CreateInstanceTest()
{
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
    Assert.IsNotNull(someClass, "Constructor could not return an instance");
    //provide failure message here
}
```

How do I do it in this test?

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void EmptyNameInConstructorThrowsExceptionTest()
{
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void EmptyNameInConstructorThrowsExceptionTest()
{
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(null);
    Assert.Fail("Exception not thrown");
}
```